# Why are those dates different?

Tags: javascript, date

Here the console output:

```
new Date(2016, 08, 22)
Thu Sep 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)

new Date("2016, 08, 22")
Mon Aug 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Different months but why ?

Comment: Different constructor are being invoked, thus different date note: months starts with `0` so when using `new Date(Year, month, date)` add +1 for month

Comment: @Satpal—exactly the same constructor is used ([*Date*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-date-constructor)). The difference is how it treats a single string argument vs a of number arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript months are 0 based in the numeric case, but in the string parsing 08 is mapped to August as it is a string translation of "August" in standard date format.
`Date` is being invoked in different ways as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

1. new Date();
2. new Date(value);
3. new Date(dateString);
4. new Date(year,month[, day[, hour[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);

In your case, 3 & 4 formats are being called.

```
>> new Date(2016, 08, 22)
>> Thu Sep 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
>> new Date(2016, 01, 22)
>> Mon Feb 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
>> new Date(2016, 0, 22)
>> Fri Jan 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
>> new Date("2016-08-22")
>> Mon Aug 22 2016 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
>> new Date("2016/08/22")
>> Mon Aug 22 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

- @RobG's input from the comments:

> ...parsing ofstrings other than ISO 8601 extended format is entirely 
>   implementation dependent. The result of parsing "2016, 08, 22" could be anything, including an invalid Date.

Comment: Your comments on parsing of strings should include that parsing of strings other than ISO 8601 extended format is entirely implementation dependent. The result of parsing "2016, 08, 22" could be anything, including an invalid Date.

Answer (score 2):

The second `Date` constructor you use is intended to parse a (known) string representation of a date, like `"Dec 25, 1995"`. The format you pass in is not a standard one, so even though the result is close to the correct date (and could be fixed by correcting the month value, as pointed out by DhruvPathak), it should not be used as results my differ depending on the runtime/browser.

Comment: Parsing of "Dec 25, 1995" with the Date constructor (or Date.parse) may produce any result, including an invalid Date. Given `new Date('Dec 25, 1995')`, Firefox returns  a syntax error.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had another look at the docs at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse which states: "If the String does not conform to the standard format the function may fall back to any implementation–specific heuristics or implementation–specific parsing algorithm." Looks like the only format guaranteed to work is ISO-8601; "other formats may be used, but results may be unexpected".

Comment: "*may well*" should be "will". Even ISO 8601 is not fully or consistently supported (certainly not guaranteed to work), and ECMA-262 itself diverges from the standard when parsing ISO 8601 dates. The bottom line is to always use a parser for strings and always specify the format to parse.

Comment: You are right, that's a great conclusion to draw from the OP's question. I never used any built-in format for date parsing, but since the API is there, people will eventually use it. Here be dragons!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately far too many do use the built–in parser then complain when things go awry. I can't count how many time's I've warned against using it, so I might be a bit sensitive to the issue… :-(